# Event Bubbling in WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, event-bubbling

I'm new to WPF. In my WPF app, I have Windows which contain a user defined child control and that user defined child control again contains another user defined child control. Now from the inner most child control, on a button click, I want to fire events on all three controls (i.e.  First Grand Child Control, Second Child Control, Third Main Control, and Window).

I know this can be achieved through delegates and Event Bubbling. Can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most important piece pf code for that:
Add the event handlers on the static UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent:

```
middleInnerControl.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent , new RoutedEventHandler(handleInner)); //adds the handler for a click event on the most out 
mostOuterControl.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent , new RoutedEventHandler(handleMostOuter)); //adds the handler for a click event on the most out
```

The EventHandlers:

```
private void handleInner(object asd, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InnerControl c = e.OriginalSource as InnerControl;
        if (c != null)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
        e.Handled = false; // do not set handle to true --> bubbles further
    }

private void handleMostOuter(object asd, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InnerControl c = e.OriginalSource as InnerControl;
        if (c != null)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
        e.Handled = true; // set handled = true, it wont bubble further
    }
```

Comment: Why not [ClickEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickevent.aspx)?

Comment: yes or course why not. Didnt read carefully enough to see that its a Button which gets clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) explains all about routed events, including how to implement and consume them.