# How do I create an overlay popup in WPF that ignores mouse events?

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, popup, mouse

How can I create a semi-transparent popup overtop of a webview control so that the popup does not intercept mouse events?  I want the mouse to interact with the underlying webview control contents, not the popup.  Is this possible?

Below is my xaml snippet:

```
    <Grid Name="windowGrid" Background="#FFDE0707">
        <StackPanel>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Controls:WebView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="wvc" Width="800" Height="800" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="http://www.google.ca" />

                <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=wvc}" Placement="Center" IsOpen="true" AllowsTransparency="True">
                    <Rectangle Height="400" Width="400"  Fill="Purple" Opacity="0.25" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                </Popup>
            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You may want to look into Event Bubbling... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452611/event-bubbling-in-wpf-application#6453057

Comment: I tried setting Event Bubbling on both the Popup and the Rectangle, and I can see the event gets bubbled up to the Grid.  But the event doesn't hit the WebView.  Is that because the Popup is not a child of the WebView?  In the handler for the Popup do I need to direct the event to the WebView somehow?

Comment: I tried using RaiseEvent on the WebView object, and I can see the WebView does get the event, but the WebView is not responding to the event.  Maybe I need to handle more than just the MouseDownEvent though.

Comment: The RaiseEvent works with other controls (like if I place a WPF button under the popup) but not the WebView control.  Maybe the WebView control doesn't respond to RaiseEvent though I don't see any notations about this in the documentation.  Looks like I am at a roadblock again.